# printing string in c# using \r\n to start new line

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, newline

I have a asp.net and c# project.

I need to print this string out, i get it like this from the server:

```
Working...: 0/0\r\nNavigating: 0/0
```

It should be printed out in 2 separate lines (using the \r\n), shouldn't it be doing that automatically?

Am i doing something wrong?

I cant change the string but the way i use it, is:
I have a EO progress bar that i send a message like this:

```
_progressBar.UpdateProgress(_count, progress.Message);
```

And it displays the message under the progressBar. 
The message is the string i posted on top.

Thanks

Comment: HTML uses `<br/>` for line breaks...

Comment: @Yahia, but i am not using any html. how can i get that string to start a new line?

Comment: use it instead of `\r\n` - you tagged this as ASP.NET which usually outputs HTML so I assume that the string you send is interpreted as HTML client-side...

Comment: I am confused - IF you can't change the string - what are you expecting then as an answer (changing nothing means the result won't change usually) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<br/>` - [that is a line break in HTML](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/br)...

EDIT - as per comment:

```
string X = @"Working...: 0/0\r\nNavigating: 0/0";
string Y = X.Replace ( @"\r\n", @"<br/>" ); // Result is Working...: 0/0<br/>Navigating: 0/0
```

Comment: Thanks,  but i am not using any html. how can i get that string to start a new line?

Comment: @Ovi use it instead of `\r\n` - you tagged this as ASP.NET which usually outputs HTML so I assume that the string you send is interpreted as HTML client-side...

Comment: can you give me please the exact syntax for replacing all "\r\n" with <br/>? thanks

Answer (score 5):

It seems like your string might contain `@"\r\n"` instead of `"\r\n"`, case in which you'd have to parse the escape characters yourself.

For example, to replace backslash-r by CR and backslash-n by LF (not the most efficient way to do it):

```
string s0 = @"A\r\nB"; // s0 would print as: A\r\nB
string s = s0.Replace(@"\r","\r").Replace(@"\n","\n");
```

Now `s` contains:

```
A
B
```

Comment: Thanks, can you be more specific in how i parse it myself?

Answer (score 1):

The server has to send to the client data that the latter understands. JSON, HTML, XML or whatever data type you're working with.

From the client's point of view `\r\n` is just a string like any other. In this case you may want to send something like:

```
Working...: 0/0<br/>Navigating: 0/0
```

And print it has HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are sending a backslash followed by an n or r and not a \r or \n.
If so you have to parse them yourself or get the output to be \r and \n

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is automatic.

```
using System;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mesg = "Working...: 0/0\r\nNavigating: 0/0";
        Console.WriteLine(mesg);
    }
}
```

> C:\temp>csc Test.cs
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved
>
> C:\temp>Test
>
> Working...: 0/0
>
> Navigating: 0/0
>
> C:\temp

Comment: So why in my case it doesnt separate the lines?

Comment: It seems like you are using string mesg = @"Working...: 0/0\r\nNavigating: 0/0"; in your program.